# Purpose of down voting if it resets after deleting

Tags: discussion, downvotes, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

If any user removes his/her down voted answers/questions the reduced reputations points will be re added to the total again.

I understand it is always good to remove the bad answers that would lead someone down a wrong path. But at the same time, what is the purpose of down voting if it can be reset as preferred?

By doing the above, does it have a bad impact on the user's profile?
Or is resetting the total reputation on delete a bug?

Comment: If a bad answer is deleted, then the downvote has served its purpose. It the user didn't get the points back, there would be less incentive to delete bad answers.

Comment: It doesn't have an impact on rep, but all downvoted posts count towards an asking/answering ban. It has no impact on high-rep users most of the time (because of the pure post count that makes a single downvoted post a drop in the ocean)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Voting is there so that we can see whether posts are useful or not. There's guidance on the tooltips about when to vote both up and down.

If you create too many downvoted posts you may be banned - question banned for bad questions and answer banned for bad answers. You can be banned whether or not your posts are deleted.

Stack has always operated on the principle that once you've deleted a post then its impact (other than contributing to a potential ban) is basically gone. If there are any upvotes, you won't get their benefit either for instance.

If you're not wasting anyone's time any more by having to read your poor quality post then why shouldn't we allow you to move on and mostly pretend it didn't happen? The rest of us can then spend more time reading and answering the good stuff.

We already get lots of complaints that this is a harsh place, if we forced everyone to live with the consequences of their poor quality posts without any hope of redemption we'd surely get even more.

Comment: Do you know why such questions receive downvotes?

Comment: I mean such questions like "Purpose of down voting if it resets after deleting" or "Is it normal to flag a question, and answer it anyway?"

Comment: According to the downvote tooltip, questions that "do not show any research effort" are candidates for downvotes. Not sure I see much of that in those questions. Also [voting is different on meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Anyway Meta voting doesn't affect your rep so it's not really something to worry about.